# 100 random numbers in the range of 1 - 20 in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am fairly new to Javascript, and so far I have manage to create the random number by using the following

```
 var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*21)+1

      document.write(+randomnumber);
```

I was thinking that I could use for loop but I am unsure how to go about this

Comment: You state what you have to do in your answer, just look up how to do a loop...

Answer (score 2):

First problem: `Math.floor(Math.random()*21)+1` will return a random integer between 1-21, not 1-20.

Second: use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add values to the end of an array.

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  arr.push((Math.floor(Math.random()*20)+1));
}
```